# Requesting link in desktop view

Tags: android, webview, webkit, android-webview

In my application,i have a **webview** which includes a link that opens on device's default browser. **Problem** is this the website redirects me to the **mobile view** of that page. Is there any way to open webpage in desktop view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setUserAgentString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString(java.lang.String)) for it:

`webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0");`

Comment: I believe this on effects my webview. Still link that opens on browser shows mobile view.

Comment: @Kdaydin Does that site load in desktop view in Chrome?

Comment: my default browser is firefox but probably it will load in mobile view in chrome as well.

Comment: [Here](https://deviceatlas.com/blog/list-of-user-agent-strings) is a list of user agent strings. Try if any of them work.